# Two digits after the decimal point in a real number in Pascal

Tags: number-formatting, pascal, real-number

So for an example i have a real number let's say 17.4578 but i want to display it in pascal with only two digits after the point so it's 17.45.
What do i write in my program?

Comment: In a console that would be: `WriteLn(AReal:0:2);`

Comment: what does the 0 stand for

Comment: @LURD - that would produce `17.46` . Not sure if that's important to the OP.

Comment: That is the width specifier.

Comment: According to Standard Pascal (ISO/IEC 7185:1990) a width specifier must be greater than or equal to one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Write(17.4578:0:2)
```

Will display number `17.46`
Generally, arguments look like this → Value : field_width : decimal_field_width
For more info click [here](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Formatting_output)

Answer (score 1):

This would work. However, if this is the last line of code always remember a readln at the end.

```
    Writeln(17.4578:0:2)
```

This would lead to 17.46 because it rounds up as it is followed by a 7.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use **:0:2** at the end of Real number:

```
writeln(17.4578:0:2)
```